# Batch extract and rename csv files from multiple folders - Python

Tags: python

I have a 350 folders in a directory that all contain two csv files named "certificates" and "recommendations". I want to move every single "certificates.csv" files into a new folder but also change the name of those .csv files in the process, adding an index number as a suffix so they do not overwrite each other i.e. "certificates1", "certificates2"...."certificates350" etc.

I managed to get to this when trying to move all the files into one folder:

```
import os
import shutil
src_dir = "C:/IN"
dst_dir = "C:/OUT"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src_dir):
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith('.csv'):
            shutil.copy(os.path.join(root,f), dst_dir)
```

But all that does is cycle through the files overwriting each other in the process as they all have the same names - "certificates.csv"

Comment: StackOverflow is a site to help people stuck with an issue, which after some time they found out they cannot solve themselves.
This means that the author of the question should show what he/she already tried, what was wrong with those approaches, i.e. did some work already.
StackOverflow is not a site for people to come and ask "do my work for instead of me free of charge".

Comment: Yes, I suggest to add these to the original question with possibly pieces of code you tried

Comment: @Vlad, as suggested, these comments of yours should be part of the question text. Comments can be deleted, and the idea is that SO is not a thread forum, but a Q&A site.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the file exists and increment a counter until filename is available:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src_dir):
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith('.csv'):
            index = 0
            while True:        
                new_path = os.path.join(dst_dir, str(index) + f)
                if os.path.isfile(new_path):
                    index += 1
                    continue

                shutil.copy(os.path.join(root, f), new_path)
                break
```

If you want a suffix, not a prefix for a file, you should split name from extension, append a number, then join again.

Comment: Suffix or prefix it doesn't matter - I just needed some differentiation between the names. Thank you, but it still didn't work for me. It only pulls out the first certificate. I found a work around through folder search on windows and managed to copy them with a number index added in brackets.